# IReturnVoid generates exception on metadata page

Tags: servicestack

The following DTO generates a NullReferenceException when I click on the JSON link on the metadata page.

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/AVideo")]
[Route("/AVideo/{VideoID}/{Filename}")]
public class PlayerVideo : IReturnVoid
{
   [DataMember]
   public Guid VideoID { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string Filename { get; set; }  //dummy
}
```

If I change the return type to `IReturn<int>`, the metadata page generates correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there's a [pull request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/799) to fix this.