# NullReferenceException on metadata page

Tags: servicestack

I have written a very basic webservice using Servicestack which works fine, but when I browse to the metadata page for this service, something seems to blow up.

A `NullReferenceException` is being thrown somewhere inside of Servicestack I believe.

I have the latest version pulled from NuGet.

The version is: 3.9.56.

The implementation of the service is simply this:

```
[Route("/hello/{Id}", "DELETE")]
public class DeleteHello : IReturnVoid
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TestService : Service
{
    public void Delete(DeleteHello request)
    {
    }
}
```

The `AppHostBase` is as simple as possible. It contains no custom configurations at all, and is hosted in the IIS Express version that comes with  Visual Studio 2012.

When I go to `http://localhost:45864/json/metadata?op=DeleteHello` the exception is thrown.

Am I doing something wrong or what is going on?

Comment: I believe it's the [same issue as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931815/ireturnvoid-generates-exception-on-metadata-page).

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be the same issue. My bad for not finding that question. Will vote to close this as a duplicate.