# ServiceStack version 3.9.56 gives NullReferenceException error at metadata json page

Tags: servicestack, nullreferenceexception

I just downloaded ServiceStack with NuGet. Version 3.9.56.

I am trying simple webservice but when i open metadata json page it gives NullReferenceException error.

My service is here:

```
[Route("/users")]
[Alias("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Alias("UserID")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class UsersService:Service
{
    public object Get(User request)
    {
        var result = new List<User>();
        result = Db.Select<User>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931815/ireturnvoid-generates-exception-on-metadata-page) that might explain your null reference exception. However, you do not want `IReturnVoid`, unlike in your other post, so the answer here is not to wait for ServiceStack to be fixed but to improve your DTO's declaration:

Your `UsersService` implementation is returning a `List<User>` object for your `User` request. You can document this in ServiceStack like so:

```
public class User : IReturn<List<User>>
{
    ...
}
```

This may fix the issue you are seeing on the metadata page as ServiceStack now knows the type of response to expect for the User message. There are other benefits to decorating your request DTOs with `IReturn`:

- The [typed C# client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API#calling-services-from-a-typed-c-client) will be easier to use, as the client can know the type of your response message
- The [Swagger UI](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API), if you use it, will know about and automatically document the response type